# Can we get line number on which particular string found in HTML Source

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a VBA crawler in which I find particular Special character from HTML Source. Now is there anyway I could find on which line this special character exist in original HTML Source??

Source File Extracted:

> src = IE.responseText

Find Special Character:

'txt' is string between two tags,
'Str' is Special Character I need in between the tags

> RESULT = InStr(1, txt, Str, vbBinaryCompare)

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code. Why not count the \n from before the found text

Comment: @mplungjan I am keeping extracted strings in "RESULT" ...just fyi some strings in Original source has lengthy sentences which are 5-6 lines but considered as one line, am I getting any sense here?

Comment: Unless you render the file, you will not get the visible line number if you cannot rely on the \n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is what I used to get line number..it works wonderful for me.

```
Open fname For Input As #1



   Do While Not EOF(1)
   Line Input #1, textline
   text = text & textline



   ' Increment Ctr since you're on the line now
   Ctr = Ctr + 1

   ' Check the current line to see if it contains the string we're looking for
   ' If it does, set Ctr2 to be the current line number

For x = 2 To LR

   Str = Sheet1.Range("A" & x).Value
   If textline Like "*" & "" & Str & "" & "*" Then
      Ctr2 = Ctr

      Exit For
   End If
Next x
   Loop

   Close #1
```